# Python function take list_A as input and return it as list_B

Tags: python, function, return

I am writing a Program that gets a list as an Input and should return one as Output.
But I'm getting my original Input. The print statement `print(mylist)` gives me the desired output but not the return of the function

```
def combination_3(mylist):
    possible_words_list_3 = []

    for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
        for j in range(0,len(mylist)):
            for k in range(0,len(mylist)):
                
                new_word = mylist[i], mylist[j], mylist[k]
                possible_words_list_3.append(new_word)
    #print(possible_words_list_3)
    mylist = possible_words_list_3.copy()
    print(mylist)
    return mylist
```

Comment: If `print(mylist)` prints the correct result then `return mylist` also returns the correct result. Probably you are not using the returned value correctly in the code where you call the function.

Comment: Side note: [`list(itertools.product(mylist, repeat=3))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the input to the function. You should return your newly-created list.

```
def combination_3(mylist):
    possible_words_list_3 = []

    for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
        for j in range(0,len(mylist)):
            for k in range(0,len(mylist)):
                
                new_word = mylist[i], mylist[j], mylist[k]
                possible_words_list_3.append(new_word)

    return possible_words_list_3
```

Comment: They are returning a copy of `possible_words_list_3`, not the argument `mylist`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I figured it out. I overwrote `mylist` like this:

```py
def combination_3(mylist):
    """returns every possible word with 3 Letters """
    possible_words_list_3 = []

    for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
        for j in range(0,len(mylist)):
            for k in range(0,len(mylist)):
                
                new_word = mylist[i], mylist[j], mylist[k]
                possible_words_list_3.append(new_word)

    for i in range(0,len(possible_words_list_3)):
        mylist.append(possible_words_list_3[i])

    return mylist
```

Comment: Note: use backticks (`\`\`\``) to fence code blocks. Not quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help